# Is there any other sources to download IBM Watson iot-device-samples.git?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-iot

I'm learning about IBM Watson IoT Platform about Device Management Protocol. but i can't access the iot-device-samples.git. Is there any other link that similar to that?

the error link : https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-device-samples/

Answer (score 0):

most of those samples can be found here:

https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot

Answer (score 0):

We restructured the samples into the repositories for each language’s client library.  So depending which language you are interested in you will find samples in the following locations:

Python: https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/tree/master/samples

Java: https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-java/tree/master/samples

NodeJS: https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-nodejs/tree/master/samples

Out of interest, where did you find the link to that old repository, if you le me know I will see if I can get it updated.